# Add gesture recognizer to BezierPath created by PaintCode

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, paintcode

I have no idea about the following situation:

I had exported a `NSObject` from PaintCode and made a .swift file (*someObject.swift*).

```
public class PlanATrip: NSObject {

    class func drawRectangle1(frame targetFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height:100), resizing: ResizingBehavior = .aspectFit) {

    ....

}
```

I also overrode the `draw()` function in a `UIView` (*someObjectView.swift*).

So how can add a gesture recognizer to a bezierPath (for example, a `rectangle1 = UIBezierPath(...)` ) which is in the *someObject.swift* ?

I tried to add some functions like:

`let tapGestureA:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touchAction))`

However, the scope confused me; like if I put the touchAction function out of the `drawRectangle1` function, I will not be able to access `rectangle1`.

How can I modify to make such a gesture recognizer work?

Comment: What is you final goal? Would you like to create a custom button? I'm asking because I see you are trying to add a "UITapGestureRecognizer". If that's the case (you would like to create a custom button), the answer is very straightforward (I can provide more details). Just wanted to confirm what your final goal is first.

Comment: @backslash-f I draw a bezierPath and want to add a TapGestureRecognizer to it. I'm not quite sure it is a "custom button".

Comment: I see, I got the picture. Please refer to my answer below. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to manipulate `UIBezierPath` objects generated by PaintCode directly, which isn't PaintCode's purpose.

What you are trying to achieve is possible, but not without some hacking.
For example: [How to access a layer inside UIView custom class generate with Paintcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526709/how-to-access-a-layer-inside-uiview-custom-class-generate-with-paintcode)

In my opinion, you are "misusing" PaintCode.

Instead, you would be much better adding the tapping logic inside your custom `UIView`. The thing you called `someObjectView.swift`.
For example: https://github.com/backslash-f/paint-code-ui-button

In case you really need to check if gestures occur inside the boundaries of a `UIBezierPath` then you need to create a public reference to it (e.g.: a `var` that points to it outside of the `drawRectangle1` function) and finally use the code proposed by @Sparky.

The main problem with this approach is that your changes **will be overwritten** every time you use PaintCode's export feature. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll think about what you said.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to add a UITapGestureRecognizer that will recognize a gesture within a portion of your view defined by a UIBezierPath.

In this case, assign the selector to the gesture recognizer as you have in your question, then in the body of touchAction(recognizer:), test whether the gesture lies within the UIBezierPath. The simple case where you only care if the gesture is inside the UIBezierPath might be handled as follows:

```
func touchAction(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
           guard rectangle1.contains(recognizer.location(in: self)) else { return }

           // Execute your code for the gesture here

           // ...

}
```